# Sencha Touch - Selector like iphone?

Tags: user-interface, sencha-touch, extjs

Does Sencha touch have the ability to create a selector similar to the iphone's selector?:
[image: http://www.designerstoolbox.com/images/iphone_selector.gif]

I did not see it in their kitchen sink demos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a Picker class which allows you to do this:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.Picker

As far as I know, there is no example of a Picker in the official examples, but you can find an example of the DatePicker at:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/picker/

In addition, you can find an (unoffical) example of a Picker at:
http://www.simoens.org/Sencha-Projects/demos/

Answer (score 2):

Sencha Touch 2.0 (now in developer preview) **does** have an iphone-like picker and you can see a demo here:

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/touch/examples/kitchensink/

Go to the User Interface / Overlays section.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware (regular Sencha Touch developer) there is no option for this yet. You could try and bastardise the DatePickerField class by extending Ext, but I think this is likely to be on the roadmap anyway.